# Maze with no dead-ends python

Tags: python

I have a function to generate a random maze given a number for rows and columns and everything get's carved out perfectly fine...what i would like to do is delete/remove any walls that might have and enclosure within the maze so that the maze has no 'dead ends'. I have tried the following but seems like it is not working...anyone see where i might be going wrong

```
def random_maze_without_deadends(row,cols):
    maze = random_maze(row,cols) #this will generate a random maze and carve out a maze where all cells are defaulted to no value
    for i in xrange(row):
        for j in xrange(cols):
            z  = maze.open_directions(i,j) # assume maze.open_direction open's up the maze by  Returning a list of open (non-wall) directions from a cell given by row column  
            walls = ['N','S','W','E'] #preassigned values for north south west and east respectively to check open 'walls' of cells
            if i == 0:
                walls.remove('N')
            if i == i -1:
                walls.remove('S')
            if j == 0:
                walls.remove('W')
            if j == j-1:
                walls.remove('E')
            if len(z) == 1:
                walls.remove(z[0])
                return maze
```

The following is what the previous code uses as well:

```
class MazeCell:
    def __init__(self, r, c):
        self.row = r
        self.col = c
        self.directions = ["N", "S", "E", "W"]
        random.shuffle(self.directions)

    def random_maze(rows,cols):
        maze = Maze(rows, cols)
        carve_passages_stack(maze)
        return maze
```

My main question is basically what's wrong with the deadend function's logic? Thanks for any attempts at trying to figure out what I mean.

UPDATE- this is my current output:

```
 _________
| |  _  | |
| |_  | | |
|_____| | |
|  __x|_  |  <---This part should get opened up---where the x is as north south and east are clos
|_________|
```

Comment: Are you trying to prevent enclosures or terminal points?

Comment: What about it does not work? Have you stepped through it with a debugger / poor man's debugger?

Comment: You still aren't editing `maze` after calculating which wall to remove.

Answer (score 1):

After doing
`walls.remove(z[0])`

your walls array now contains only directions that are walls for your dead end. But you don't then edit maze to take out one of the walls remaining.

Also, you should do a check right after initializing z to make sure `len(z) == 1` - if not, `continue` to the next cell. This will save processing time.

Answer (score 0):

`walls` is just a list.

```
walls = ['N','S','W','E']
```

`walls.remove(z[0])` affects `walls`, but it does not alter `maze`.
You need to inspect the methods and/or data structure used by Maze objects and determine how to remove a wall from cell `(i,j)` when `len(z) == 1`.

Also, the `return maze` line needs to be de-dented so the `random_maze_without_deadends` *always* returns a maze.